# Htaccess redirect question

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site I've written in php.

**The addresses are as follows:**
http://www.site.com/page.php

**I'd like any request to:**
www.site.com/page.php
or
www.site.com/page

**To go to:**
www.site.com/page/

(And force a www.)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

For domain :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For your first directory :

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)(\.php)? /$1/
```

Comment: This appears to be redirecting from `http://domain.com/page` to `http://www.domain.com`, not not preserving the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^page.php$ http://www.site.com/page/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^page$ http://www.site.com/page/ [QSA,L]
```

Maybe this will work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you wanted:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  ^[A-Z]+\s/([^\s]*?)\.php    [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  ^[A-Z]+\s/([^\s]*?[^/\s])\s [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 ^(www\.)?(.*?)/?$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%2/ [R=301,L]

# Assuming you want to write the request back to page.php too...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is the closest, but it also does adds the trailing slash to images and css...

So taking Tim's answer, and slightly editing it gives us:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  ^[A-Z]+\s/([^\s]*?)\.php    [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  ^[A-Z]+\s/([^\s]*?[^/\s])\s [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 ^(www\.)?(.*?)/?$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%2/ [R=301,L]

# Assuming you want to write the request back to page.php too...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

Which should work!